# emerge /etc/portage/make.profile is not a symlink during Gentoo installation?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I cannot run `emerge-webrsync` because it says that snapshots are not found.

Nor can I execute `mirrorselect`, since I get command not found.

Finally, I tried to run:

```
$ emerge --ask app-portage/mirrorselect
```

but this returns the following error:

```
!!! Repository 'x-portage' is missing masters attribute in '/usr/portage/metadata/layout.conf'
!!! Set 'masters = gentoo' in this file for future compatibility


!!! /etc/portage/make.profile is not a symlink and will probably prevent most merges.
!!! It should point into a profile within /usr/portage/profiles/
!!! (You can safely ignore this message when syncing. It's harmless.)


!!! Your current profile is invalid. If you have just changed your profile
!!! configuration, you should revert back to the previous configuration.
!!! Allowed actions are limited to --help, --info, --search, --sync, and
!!! --version.
```

Comment: What step of the handbook are you at? Are you trying to do these commands inside or outside of the chroot environment?

Comment: I am doing inside chroot.Outside everything works. I am trying to do eselect profile list and getting error Failed to get a list of valid profiles
exiting

Comment: I'm on the step right after chrooting

Comment: also my /usr/portage dir is empty

Comment: it's solved. All I had to do was run emerge --sync and wait

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `eselect profile list` and then select the right profile with `eselect profile set ...` command.  The gentoo handbook suggest to use the same profile as the tarbal / livecd you used to install gentoo on your hdd.  Then you should be able to use `emerge --sync` and `emerge -DuNa world` to update your system.